# C# Reading Excel Data From Cells in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel

I am writing a C# Console Application and I am correctly opening an Excel file. I just can't figure out how to read data from cells and copy it into an array. Most of the code I have found list examples that won't work with VS 2010. It appears they have changed how to read cell data in every version. I am wanting to read a variable amount of rows depending on how long the data goes. I am wanting to read cells [B8]-[*8].

I have spend a couple of days on this without much luck.

Thanks very much,
BuZzZzJaY

Comment: Couple of questions. What are the specific errors/problems you're having and are you using Excel Interop from Microsoft or a 3rd part library?

Comment: I am using Excel Interop. All of the examples I have found on how to read cell date contains data types and function that are not used in Excel Interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method
workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.EntireColumn

use bellow code this is 2d array. Iterate in this

Object[,] obj = (object[,])sheet.get_Range("A1", "B4").Value2;

Comment: But how do I load it into an array?

Comment: BTW if your only using the open format (xlsx) you can use ExcelPackage [1] which has some what simple (simplest?) interface.
[1] http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/